# ASP.NET Core SignalR Client WSS Issue

Tags: asp.net-core-signalr

I have a console application (client) with package 
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client` installed. I'm trying to connect to wss and send request (also get the response) but I couldn't figure it out how to achieve that.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR.Client;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace ConsoleClient
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Press a key to start listening");
            Console.ReadKey();
            var connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
                .WithUrl("wss://api.acme.com/ws")
                .AddJsonProtocol()
                .Build();

            /*

               WORK

            */

            connection.StartAsync().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

            Console.WriteLine("Listening. Press a key to quit");
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Request Message

`{ "event": "ping" }`

Response Message

`{ "event": "pong"}`

EDIT : I think I got it wrong. With `HubConnectionBuilder` class I can only connect to a hub, right? If yes, then how can I connect to ws?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I guess the problem is I'm trying to connect web socket via directly signalr and it's not possible. Anyone?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Hi David. I have an idea for my app which is a web api application connects to more than one websocket endpoint (exchanges) then publishes data via signalR. I couldn't find a proper way to connect to websocket with .net core. I tought I can connect to websocket via signalr but this is not correct, I guess?

Comment: The API to connect to a websocket end point is ClientWebSocket. SignalR is a layer above this with a custom protocol for doing RPC.